# oracle DBMS error: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "USER1.S"

Tags: oracle, database

All a sudden i get this error when i try to add a new procedure in my package or rename procedure name. it looks like something is locked not allowing me to add or modify new procedures. could anyone explain what goes wrong here?

> ERROR at line 1:     ORA-04063: package body "USER1.S" has errors
>   ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "USER1.S"
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: Are you creating a package called `S` in schema `USER1`, or have you created it and are now trying to call it? It looks like creation failed ('package compiled with warnings'?), but you're still calling it, perhaps. Try 'show errors' after creating the package (from SQL*Plus), or 'show errors package body s', and add any errors it shows to the question.

Comment: yes, S is the package i created under USER1. inside S, i have a procedure, called find_information, it runs perfectly without any problem until i rename it to find_info(both specification and body). this also happen when i define a new procedure...
between, there's no error when i run the script

Comment: Are you calling that procedure within the package - have you updated all references, not just the name? Does `show errors` say anything?

Comment: yeah, i am pretty sure i updated everything. actually it is a simple procedure. so there's not much references i have to deal with. and this is what i get when i run the script > 
Package created.
No errors.

Comment: So what do you do to generate the ORA-04063? After you get that what does `show errors package user1.s` show, and does `alter package user1.s compile` succeed?

Comment: hey, i got it working. thanks for helping me out! greatly appreciated!